# passing numpy array to tensorflow queue

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I have a tensorflow model which works fine, I was using feed_dict but I'm trying to change that to a queuing operations to increase the performance.

old code

```
            p_boxes = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name("con:0")
            p_confs = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name("sha:0")
            x = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name("x_in:0")    
            feed_dict_testing = {x: x_batch}
            np_pred_confs, np_pred_boxes = sess.run([pred_confs, 
            pred_boxes], feed_dict=feed_dict_testing)
```

Above is my old code where I pass a numpy array object of shape - (1024,1024,3) and the predictions worked fine.

With the new code Im trying to simulate a simple code passing a numpy array of the same size but I get this following error.

```
ValueError: Fetch argument <tf.Tensor 'sha:0' shape=(1024, 1, 2) dtype=float32> cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Tensor Tensor("sha_4:0", shape=(1024, 1, 2), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.)
```

New code:-

```
a  = np.zeros((1024, 1024, 3))
dtypes=[tf.float32]
print len(dtypes)
shapes=[1024, 1024, 3]
print len(shapes)
q = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=200,dtypes=dtypes,shapes=shapes)


enqueue_op = q.enqueue(a)
qr = tf.train.QueueRunner(q, [enqueue_op] * 1)
tf.train.add_queue_runner(qr) 
data = q.dequeue()
p_boxes = graph.get_tensor_by_name("con:0")
p_confs = graph.get_tensor_by_name("sha:0")
x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("x_in:0")

with tf.Session() as sess:
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)            
    confs, boxes = sess.run([p_confs, p_boxes])
    print boxes, confs
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `graph.get_tensor_by_name(..)` inside a `with graph.as_default():` then you should be able to have access to the element.

Or it might be the name of your tensor that is wrong. You can check the name of your operations in your graph with :

```
sess = tf.Session()
op = sess.graph.get_operations()
print [m.values() for m in op][1]
```